# Tesseract OCR finds too few boxes / ignores small characters

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I have a problem with the training/text recognition process with Tesseract. Here is my trainingdata: http://s11.postimg.org/867aq10ur/dot_dotmatrixfont_exp0.png While training Tesseract ignores the dashes (I've marked them with red boxes, just to make it clear which ones I mean) and if I'm using the trained data for text recognition it also ignores them. Today I've played around with the Tesseract parameters (SetVariable(name, value)) but unfortunately I had no success.
What can I do to teach Tesseract those dashes? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Tesserect training is pretty tricky.

Your best chance might be to handle the dashes as a single char. 
If your box editor or whatever tools you are using does not see the dashes as all, try running some image processing first, especially threshold or invert. try taking a look at OpenCV. They have some excellent tool for this kind of image processing.

Comment: I'm already using OpenCV for preprocessing and the Qt Box Editor for editing the boxfile. I create the boxfile directly by calling "tesseract dot.dotmatrixfont.exp0.tif dot.dotmatrixfont.exp0 batch.nochop makebox", so the boxeditor can't see the dashes, because there was no box created for them. If I force Tesseract to learn them as a character by manually creating a box, the recognition is totally ruined...

Comment: You need to be able to see the dashes in the  boxeditor without adding the box your self. Otherwise your in trouble as you have already discovered.  I think you need to tweak opencv's image processing until you can se the dashes. Also make sure the dashes are actual glyphs in the font you use and make sure they are not in the character ignore list